# Can you find a Polynomial of Degree 7 that has 2 complex roots and 5 real?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Can you find a Polynomial of Degree 7 that has 2 complex roots and 5 real?

The polynomial, call it $f(x)$ **must be irreducible** over $\mathbb{Q}$ 
(or over $\mathbb{Z}$ as Gauss' lemma can be used.) and have **integer coefficients**.
I have no idea how to generate such a polynomial.

I've tried things along the lines of
$f(x) = x^5(x^2 - 5) + 5$

As these are easily irreducible with Eisenstein Criterion $(p = 5)$

Peter has kindly shown (via brute force) that $$x^7+x^6-3x^5-x^4-2x^3-3x^2+x+1$$

Matches said criterion, yet has yet to show that this is irreducible. Can anyone do this?

---

Thank you to achille hui who has given me my answer of:

$f(x) = x^7+1000003(x−1)(x−2)(x−3)(x−4)(x−5)$

which is irreducible by Eisenstein's with $p = 1000003$.

Comment: I assume you mean irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Comment: What about $(x^2+1)x^5$?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen That's reducible.

Comment: Another possibility is taking any monic integer polynomial $m(x)$ with 5 real distinct roots (different from zero) and consider polynomial of the form $x^7 + p m(x)$ for sufficiently large prime $p$. e.g. $x^7 + 1000003 (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$ fullfil your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility is taking any monic integer polynomial $m(x)$ with 5 real distinct roots (different from zero) and consider polynomial of the form $x^7+pm(x)$ for sufficiently large prime p. e.g.

$f(x) = x^7+1000003(x−1)(x−2)(x−3)(x−4)(x−5)$

which is irreducible by Eisenstein's with $p = 1000003$.

Credit - achille hui. Posted as anwser rather than comment for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I searched a polynomial with the desired properties with a simple PARI-program :

? gef=0;while(gef==0,x=vector(8,n,random(5)-3);f=Pol(x);if(poldegree(f)==7,if(po
lisirreducible(f)==1,if(polsturm(f)==5,gef=1))));print(x)
[1, 1, -3, -1, -2, -3, 1, 1]
? f
%9 = x^7 + x^6 - 3*x^5 - x^4 - 2*x^3 - 3*x^2 + x + 1
? factor(f)
%10 =
[x^7 + x^6 - 3*x^5 - x^4 - 2*x^3 - 3*x^2 + x + 1 1]

? polroots(f)
%11 = [-2.204324318649112296500613456 + 0.E-28*I, -0.826822651324028965973042087
7 + 0.E-28*I, -0.5202407805205017136797052000 + 0.E-28*I, 0.56879782917907405112
96444628 + 0.E-28*I, 1.718030795521740576069959364 + 0.E-28*I, 0.132279562896414
1744768784582 + 1.030409728847455964396114753*I, 0.1322795628964141744768784582
- 1.030409728847455964396114753*I]~

? polsturm(f)
%12 = 5
?

The found polynomial is :

x^7 + x^6 - 3*x^5 - x^4 - 2*x^3 - 3*x^2 + x + 1

Better formatted :

$$x^7+x^6-3x^5-x^4-2x^3-3x^2+x+1$$

Comment: $x^7 + x^6 - 3*x^5 - x^4 - 2*x^3 - 3*x^2 + x + 1$ does indeed satisfy this, but can you show me this is irreducible? I'm assuming you need to shift it as Eisenstien's is not met.

Comment: I have not claimed that I can prove it. I only searched for such a polynomial. If this is not what you want, I will delete my answer.

Comment: No please keep it, you've answered part of my question, It just remains to be shown that it is indeed irreducible.

Comment: perhaps you could continue the search?

Comment: It wasn't me! let your haters be your motivators!